# How to include a missing PHP function that is supposed to be built-in?

Tags: php, built-in

I am trying to make a function call to `unixtojd()` in my PHP code. According to the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unixtojd.php), `unixtojd()` is a built-in function in PHP 4, 5, and 7 (I am using 5.6.40), but my PHP script fails when I try to call it.

I noticed my PHP did not throw any error even though it failed to execute after the function call. I inserted the following code:

```
    echo "unixtojd() exists?", function_exists("unixtojd") ? "Yes" : "No";

    $jd = unixtojd(); echo "jd";
```

Expected output: `unixtojd() exists? Yesjd`

Actual output: `unixtojd() exists? No`

And that is where my script terminates. Any idea on how I can remedy this or a workaround? I am not sure if it is a bug or an error on my part.

Comment: It's not necessarily a built-in function → https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php Might depend on your distribution.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I may have to speak with my system administrator to take care of that. Is there a way to enable calendar on a specific page or directory, or would have to be server-wide.

Comment: You're using a version of PHP that was released 4 years ago, and is no longer current. Upgrade to PHP 7.2 or later.

Comment: I can only work with the given system; I do not have the privileges to update/change it. Any insight to the question would be appreciated however

Comment: Alternatively: [Convert unix timestamp to julian](//stackoverflow.com/q/466321) // or look for a different userland implementation (Carbon or PEAR Date perhaps?)

Comment: @mario could you make your original response an answer so that I can mark it as best answer

Comment: The alternative was also a good suggestion, but as far as I could tell I would have still needed to enable calendar or rewrite my code completely.